# How can i change the value if the checkbox changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the problem here?

```js
if (status == "redbricks") {
  var total = area * $(".a2:checked").attr("price");
}
```

this part works but this doesn't part makes the total 'NAN'

```js
else if (status == "redbricks") {
                    var total = ('1.2' * area * $(".a3:checked").attr("price"));
```

Full code for this part

```js
var area = $(".area-input").val(),
  total = 0,
  status = $(".status-select:checked").val();
if (status == "redbricks") {
  var total = area * $(".a2:checked").attr("price");
} else if (status == "redbricks") {
  var total = "1.2" * area * $(".a3:checked").attr("price");
}
```

The problem isn't in 'Else if' I replaced turns to be

```js
if ((status == "redbricks") & ($(".package-select").val() == "1")) {
  var total = area * $(".a3:checked").attr("price") + area * 200;
} else if ($(".package-select").val() == "2") {
  var total = area * $(".a2:checked").attr("price");
}
```

and the If part isn't working now
Here is the HTML code
The first part connected to the (if) part

```html
<label class="need-job-icon-text text-center ml-4 mr-4 mt-2">
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="package"
    value="2"
    price="75"
    class="j-checkbox package-select a2" />
  <span class="need-job-text-inner">
    <span class="checkbox-circle-mark position-absolute"> </span>
    <span class="need-job-icon">
      <img src="package2.png" />
    </span>
    <span class="need-job-text">
      <span
        style="color:#FFFFFF!important"
        class="text-uppercase need-job-title"
        >a2 title</span
      >
      <span class="text-capitalize need-job-text">
        <div class="d-none"></div></span></span></span
></label>
```

The second part of the code (Else if part)

```html
<label class="need-job-icon-text text-center ml-4 mr-4 mt-2">
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="package"
    value="1"
    price="1000"
    class="j-checkbox package-select a3"
  />
  <span class="need-job-text-inner">
    <span class="checkbox-circle-mark position-absolute"> </span>
    <span class="need-job-icon">
      <img src="main.png" />
    </span>
    <span class="need-job-text">
      <span
        style="color:#FFFFFF!important"
        class="text-uppercase need-job-title"
        >a3 title</span
      >
      <span class="text-capitalize need-job-text">
        <div style="font-size: 15px;color:#FFFFFF;">
          <a
            href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-lM1MwUUIZd0/YRHAQLcsJQI/AAAAAAAABEI/Ft8JTRf93nsgqedy6Af5vobFyW4kfhy6wCLcBGAsYHQ/s16000/Mainpackage.png"
            target="_blank"
          >
            عرض التفاصيل
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none"></div>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Redbricks part <label class="need-job-icon-text text-center"><input type="radio" name="status" value="redbricks" class="j-checkbox status-select"><span class="need-job-text-inner"><span class="checkbox-circle-mark position-absolute"> </span><span class="need-job-icon"><img src="wallbrick.png"></span><span class="need-job-text"><span style='color:#FFFFFF!important' class="text-uppercase need-job-title">red bricks</span></span></span></label>

Comment: ```$(".a3:checked").attr("price")``` seems to return ```undefinded```. Maybe the checkbox is not ```checked``` when this line runs and it cant find the element?

Comment: There are 8 of inputs with class='a3' and it's necessary to make one of them checked before going to the steps after

Comment: In the elseif part you try to multiply a string '1.2' with numbers (I assume).  That will cause a NaN error.

Comment: There are 3 inputs with a2 class too

Comment: i changed it now from

var total = ('1.2' * area * $(".a3:checked").attr("price"));

to

var total = (area * $(".a3:checked").attr("price") + area * 200);

to make the result truly done and the problem is still here, CharlesEF.

Comment: @CharlesEF Suprisingly multiplying numbers with strings actually works

Comment: @Tobias S  I will admit it has been many years since I made that mistake and never tried it again.  I'm surprised you say it works now.

Comment: The problem isn't in Else if i replaced turns an the problem now in If (Also updated the post with more details)

Comment: your Else if part has `&` (bitwise AND) instead of `&&` (logical AND)

Comment: done and it doesn't work too, Any thing to do with equal symbol numbers in the javascript code?

Comment: @12321  I will admit I only glanced at the code for possible NaN errors.   All you need to do was remove the single quotes around the 1.2 value.  I normally use 'parseInt' or 'parseFloat' to make sure I'm working with numbers.  Even if browsers do support multiplying strings with numbers I would still err on the safe side.  In other words try using the parse... commands to make sure you're working with numbers.

Comment: Removed them and a3 part still getting NaN result instead of the price :P

Comment: Can you type the code after ?

Comment: It broke some other codes, Especially next buttons.

Comment: @12321  I just noticed you have a 'price' attribute in the checkbox HTML.  That is not a valid attribute.  If you want to assign a price to the checkbox you should use a data- attribute.

Comment: Never heard about it before, How does it work?

Comment: @12321  You can search for more info but where you have 'price="75"' should be 'data-price="75"'.  In javascript you use the getAttribute() command to get the value.  I use this method to support older IE versions < 11.  Looks like you use jQuery, I don't do jQuery so I can't help there.

Comment: @12321  If you don't care about older IE versions you can use obj.dataset.price

Comment: Only one of them is getting solved as usual.
anything to put in the line before if? I feel that it's opened on the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed it to that and worked!
Thanks for everyone who helped here, guys. <3

```
$(".print-page").show();
                /// a2 . a3
                var area = ($(".area-input").val()),
                    total = 0,
                    status = $(".status-select:checked").val(),
                    package =  $(".package-select:checked").val();
                if ((status == "redbricks") && (package == "yes" )) {
                    var total = (area * 200) + (area * $(".package-select:checked").attr("price"));
                } if ((status == "redbricks") && (package == "non" )) {
                    var total = (area * $(".package-select:checked").attr("price"));
                } else if (status == "half") {
                    var total = (area * $(".package-select:checked").attr("price"));
                }
```

Also changed a3 inputs' value from "1" to "yes"
And a2 inputs' value from "2" to "non"

Comment: Great that you got it working.  Can you add the HTML to your answer?  Based on your code it has changed.